# Change position for array value in JavaScript from any to last

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty sure it cannot be simpler thing to do, hence why I cannot find anything useful about this. Invoking deletion of the element and pushing it so that it becomes last seems too ugly for this.

Five values in an array:

```
 var array = ['cat', 'dog', 'turtle', 'zebra', 'pterodactylus'];
```

So, I just want dog to get pushed at the end of the array:

```
 var array = ['cat', 'turtle', 'zebra', 'pterodactylus', 'dog'];
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Yeah, pretty simple. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? Or maybe you expect to get served? Sorry but Stack Overflow is not a restaurant.

Comment: Instead of giving you a copy/paste answer, a link to the Array object documentation at MDN might help you better in the long run ;-) Read carefully, it should have all the info you need to make this work (And don't hesitate to ask if you have a specific question)  --  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: This is available free of charge, read it from start to finish and you'll have the answer in a few hours.

http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Otherwise google opera web curriculum. 

This applies to anyone googling for the answer to the above question.

Comment: You ever you an associative array or object literal? It may completely eliminate your problem, not that I'm sure exactly what it is.

Comment: @Relic There are no associative arrays in Javascript.

Comment: @bazmegakapa uhhh.. you have a lot to learn my friend...: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: @Relic If one wants to call it an associative array, they certainly can. Still, they are not arrays. The fact that you can access object properties through the array notation certainly does not make them one. And yes, all of us has a lot to learn, I am not an exception.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Yes I'm aware that everything is an 'object' but that doesn't hide the fact that associative type arrays are syntactically real in JavaScript. So you can be as pretentious as you want about it, but the community as a whole calls it that as a reference, unless you feel like saying "...you can access object properties through the array notation..." every time then go for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function moveToBack( array, index ) {
    array.push( array.splice( index, 1 )[0] );
}
```

Comment: @ldiqual: Wait... what? -1 for answering the question? +1 from me.

Comment: @ldiqual okay so +1 for giving an ANSWER instead of just commenting... can I say "tool" on here?

Comment: This answers my worries that deleting the value and pushing it is the only solution.